# JSON Files getting crawled suddenly

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, json-ld, shopify, crawl-budget

Just noticed that GSC has recently taken an interest in the .json files that are associated to all of the product pages on Shopify, and is now crawling them, but wasn't before.

Should I be worried about this? Any reason that this would suddenly have happened?

Answer (score 4):

After crawling the page Google wants to render the page to look at the content.

It may be the rendering that wants to see what if any additional information appears on the page.

The information collected by rendering with then go to the ranking.

**I would not worry unless Google spends too much time on these resources.**

The additional information may help with providing more keywords for search if the json results modify the page.